# Rename command with regular expression not working

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I want to rename files using regex.

For example: replace pattern `Mod[0-9][0-9]` to `Mod[0-9][0-9]_temp` in files `N_Mod10_m.bdf` and `N_Mod11_n.bdf` using below command:

```
rename 's/\(.*Mod[0-9][0-9]\)\(.*\.bdf\)/$1_temp$2 *
```

but this is not working.

Comment: you are missing the closing `'` in the `rename` command.

Comment: Also, if you are doing `$1_temp`, bash will look for the variable `1_temp`. To say, `$1` + `_temp`, say `${1}_temp`.

Comment: You need to use non-greedy pattern: `(.*?)`, I guess, this is what you are looking for: `rename 's/(.*?Mod[0-9][0-9])(.*?\.bdf)/$1_temp$2' *`. Have a look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19807/renaming-files-to-have-lower-case-extensions-with-rename.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use non-greedy pattern: `(.*?)`. Also, add the missing quote `'`.

I guess, this is what you are looking for: `rename 's/(.*?Mod[0-9][0-9])(.*?\.bdf)/$1_temp$2' *`.

Have a look at [Rename Multiple Files in a Shell Prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html) and [Renaming files to have lower case extensions with rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19807/renaming-files-to-have-lower-case-extensions-with-rename).

For CentOS, you can insert `_temp` into file name like this:

```
for i in *; do j=`echo $i | sed -r 's/(.*?Mod[0-9][0-9])(.*?\.bdf)/\1_temp\2/g'`; mv "$i" "$j"; done
```

Comment: This is not working. even simple replace is also not working, like rename xyz_d.txt to xya_d.txt using command rename 's/xyz/xya/' * but the alternative way, rename xyz xya * is working.

Comment: Maybe `rename 's/(.*?Mod[0-9][0-9])(.*?\.bdf)\$1_temp$2//' *` will work for you? (Adaptation of http://serverfault.com/questions/5685/renaming-files-in-linux-with-a-regex). Also, see a comment there: "On Arch Linux this is perl-rename". Is yours Arch Linux?

Comment: Please have a try with my update. If still not working, try escaping round brackets and the backslash: **for i in \*; do j=\`echo $i | sed 's/\\(.*?Mod[0-9][0-9]\\)\\(.*?\\.bdf\)/\1_temp\2/g'\`; mv "$i" "$j"; done**.